# ILog Elixir ColumnChart3D Labels not formating properly

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, ilog-elixir

I've looked through all IBM doc and Adobe livedocs, My labels for my columns which are loading dynamically are not centered properly under the columns. Here is the component code. The labels are  off center to the left, and some overlap the one left of where it should be. I tried adding styles to several different areas but couldn't get it:

```
        <ilog:ColumnChart3D id="columnChart" dataProvider="{chartData}" showDataTips="true" elevationAngle="5" projectionType="oblique" width="90%" height="100%"
                            rotationAngle="2" lightLatitude="0" lightLongitude="0"
                            ambientLight="0.1" 
                            totalDepth="2"  zoom="1" >
            <ilog:horizontalAxis>
                <mx:CategoryAxis dataProvider="{chartData}"
                                 categoryField="{chartCatField}"/>

            </ilog:horizontalAxis>  

        </ilog:ColumnChart3D>
    <mx:Legend dataProvider="{columnChart}" right="0" bottom="0" />
</s:Panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

The 3D charts axis renderer labels layout is not as smart as the one of the 2D charts due to the layout in a 3D space that is not as easy.

You can try to labelRotation property on the AxisRenderer3D to rotate the labels so that they don't collapse. Or reduce their size using the fontSize property on the same object.

```
<ilog:ColumnChart3D ...>
   ...
   <ilog:horizontalAxisRenderer>
     <ilog:AxisRenderer3D labelRotation="30" fontSize="8"/>
   </ilog:horizontalAxisRenderer>
</ilog:ColumnChart3D>
```

You can also remove some labels using the canDropLabels property is needed.

FYI IBM ILOG Elixir does have specific forum [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/category.jspa?categoryID=276) where you can find information on the product.